# Using v-tooltip inside v-menu activator in vuetify 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

How to use v-tooltip inside v-menu activator with vuetify 2.0? Previously it was working using `slot="activator"`.

That's what I'm trying to combine:

```html
<v-menu>
  <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
    <v-btn v-on="on">Menu Trigger</v-btn>
  </template>
  <!-- list with menu options -->
</v-menu>
```

and

```html
<v-tooltip v-slot:activator="{on}">
  <v-btn v-on="on">Menu Trigger with Tooltip</v-btn>
  <span>Tooltip Content</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Now I try to paste v-tooltip inside v-menu, what should happen with {on} here?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I think you're most likely unsure about the "conflicted" `on` objects passed to the template by **multiple** `activator` slots and how to apply all of the event handlers on the target element(s).

If that's the case, you can workaround this by assigning either one (or both) of them to a variable with a **different name** (see: [assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)), and then destructure and "restructure", which basically glues them back together (or `merge` them, technically speaking).

```html
<v-menu>
  <template #activator="{ on: onMenu }">
    <v-btn v-on="onMenu">Menu Trigger</v-btn>

    <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template #activator="{ on: onTooltip }">
        <v-btn v-on="{ ...onMenu, ...onTooltip }">Menu Trigger with Tooltip</v-btn>
      </template>

      <span>Tooltip Content</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>

  <!-- ...list with menu options... -->
</v-menu>
```

Or, use the slot props directly. Just make sure to name them properly so they won't introduce another naming conflict with the component's data and/or props.

```html
<v-menu>
  <template #activator="menu">
    <v-btn v-on="menu.on">Menu Trigger</v-btn>

    <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template #activator="tooltip">
        <v-btn v-on="{ ...menu.on, ...tooltip.on }">Menu Trigger with Tooltip</v-btn>
      </template>

      <span>Tooltip Content</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>

  <!-- ...list with menu options... -->
</v-menu>
```

#### Complete Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { title: 'Item #1' },
      { title: 'Item #2' },
      { title: 'Item #3' }
    ]
  })
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-menu>
    <template #activator="{ on: onMenu }">
      <v-btn v-on="onMenu">Menu Trigger</v-btn>

      <v-tooltip bottom>
        <template #activator="{ on: onTooltip }">
          <v-btn v-on="{ ...onMenu, ...onTooltip }">Menu Trigger with Tooltip</v-btn>
        </template>

        <span>Tooltip Content</span>
      </v-tooltip>
    </template>

    <v-list>
      <v-list-tile 
        v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"
        @click.prevent>
        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
  </v-menu>
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax has changed with vuetify 2.3.1: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus/#menu-with-activator-and-tooltip

Comment: @LiebsterKamerad I don't think anything has really changed. You might mean the [shorthand for `v-slot`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-slot) (`#`), which I have used in my example above.

Comment: @YomT. thanks for this answer, helped me a lot! However, I have <v-dialog> and <v-tooltip> on a button. When I hover, I see the tooltip, that is fine. Then, I click on the button and it opens the dialog, also fine. However, when I click the 'close' button for the dialog, it closes it, but the button stays focused and the tooltip is visible until I click somewhere else on the screen. Is there a pre-built way to disable this or I have to do this manually on dialog close, e.g. js method to unfocus the btn?