# How is the "..." in nested activation actually working? (Vuetify)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, spread-syntax

In a nested activation thing we have this:

`v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }">`
not `v-on="{ tooltip, menu }">`

ie:

```
<template>

  <v-tooltip>

    <template v-slot:activator="{on : tooltip}">
      <v-menu>

        <template v-slot:activator="{ on : menu }">

          <v-btn  v-on="{ ...tooltip, ...menu }">
          </v-btn>
        </template>
       
          <v-card>

          </v-card>

        </v-menu>
    </template>

       {{ tooltip_message }}

    </v-tooltip>

</template>
```

See https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations for alternate example

The `...` appears to be needed. This is the " Destructure and "restructure"" approach. ie [Using v-tooltip inside v-menu activator in vuetify 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075400/using-v-tooltip-inside-v-menu-activator-in-vuetify-2-0)

The docs here
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Destructuring-Slot-Props
don't mention anything about "...".

What do the `...` really mean in this context?

Comment: It unpacks whatever is in the object. See it as flattening the object by reducing its level of nesting by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, this is a JavaScript construct, not a Vue construct.

Consider the following, where `tooltip` and `menu` are both objects:

```js
const obj = { ...tooltip, ...menu }
```

This creates a new object. The properties of `tooltip` are copied across and then the properties of `menu`. The net result is that it merges the two objects into a new object. Properties from `menu` take precedence over those from `tooltip` if they share the same name.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals

Contrast that with this:

```js
const obj = { tooltip, menu }
```

That would just be a shorthand for this:

```js
const obj = { tooltip: tooltip, menu: menu }
```

We're still creating a new object but this time it just has two properties, called `tooltip` and `menu`. The original two objects are used as the values for those properties.

The `v-on` in your example works exactly the same way.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like spread syntax is "new" for ES6. https://codeburst.io/javascript-es6-the-spread-syntax-f5c35525f754