# Merging multiple v-slot:activator and v-on in vuetify templates

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to create reusable modal window that should be called by pressing on an icon on each of the v-data-table row. Besides, each icon should have a tooltip on mouse hover.

According to vuetify docs, both actions is using same constructions: `v-slot:activator="{ on }"` and `v-on="on"`. The question is - is there's a way in Vue/Vuetify to merge this constructions and get the desired behavior?

At the moment I found one way to get what I want by adding addtional `<a>` tag:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="tableItems">
    <template v-slot:item="props">
      <tr>
        <td>{{ props.item.text }}</td>
        <td>
          <some-modal>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <a v-on="on">
                <v-tooltip bottom>
                  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                    <v-icon v-on="on" small class="mr-2">delete</v-icon>
                  </template>
                  <span>Tooltip message</span>
                </v-tooltip>
              </a>
            </template>
          </some-modal>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

But maybe there are any ways to merge `v-slot:activator` and `v-on` without an addtional `<a>` tag?

[Codesandbox with current behavior](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-frog-zx12b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stumbled upon solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075400/using-v-tooltip-inside-v-menu-activator-in-vuetify-2-0), credits to @Yom T.

```html
<v-menu>
  <template #activator="{ on: onMenu }">
    <v-btn v-on="onMenu">Menu Trigger</v-btn>

    <v-tooltip bottom>
      <template #activator="{ on: onTooltip }">
        <v-btn v-on="{ ...onMenu, ...onTooltip }">Menu Trigger with Tooltip</v-btn>
      </template>

      <span>Tooltip Content</span>
    </v-tooltip>
  </template>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: Yes, it helps to solve the problem. Thanks for paying attention! :)